# How to order @Aspect

Tags: spring, spring-aop

In a (Spring boot) application using a lot of `@Aspect`

1. How would you ensure the correct aspects ordering with `@Order`, knowing that you can't have a central place to define the ordering since these aspects may reside in different libs used by different applications?
2. How would you list all the `@Aspect` present in the application context, an their order ?
3. Does it make sense to use `@DeclarePrecedence` in a separate `@Aspect` to ensure the ordering instead of `@Order` for such a use case ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Spring user, but AFAIK `@DeclarePrecedence` is not implemented in Spring AOP, it only affects pure AspectJ aspects, i.e. if you use LTW with AspectJ it would work, otherwise you are stuck with `@Order` plus special values like `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` and `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`.

IMO if you get problems with aspect precedence your design is flawed. An aspect should implement a cross-cutting concern and be independent of other aspects. Of course there are exceptions to every rule, but those should only affect aspects from one library which could sometimes be interdependent. Aspects from different libs should not make any assumptions about order. So if this is a real problem in your code base and not just a theoretical question - **go refactor!**

Comment: It is not clear to me if `@DeclarePrecedence` is honored by spring AOP, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-2205

Comment: The problem for me is that you can have cross-cutting concerns tackled in separate libs, for example, if you have a dedicated lib handling distributed tracing and another one handling transactions, how do you ensure which one is executed first?

Comment: Why would that be an issue anyway? Tracing and transaction handling should not affect each other. But as long as the libs are developed in the same company and if you really think you need this, you can agree on number ranges for each library, clarifying on a global scale which libs should have higher preference than others. I still think it is a bad idea, though. You will get bad interdependencies if people start relying on that  because things will break if someone starts to refactor an aspect lib.